# Webpage layout mistake on first load of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My web page has 3 links at the top of the page: *Login*, *Sign Up* and *Forgot password*. Clicking on one will give you the specific form you requested.

However, when the page is first loaded or refreshed, it will show both the sign up and login forms on the same page.

```
$('.form').find('input, textarea').on('keyup blur focus', function(e) {

  var $this = $(this),
    label = $this.prev('label');

  if (e.type === 'keyup') {
    if ($this.val() === '') {
      label.removeClass('active highlight');
    } else {
      label.addClass('active highlight');
    }
  } else if (e.type === 'blur') {
    if ($this.val() === '') {
      label.removeClass('active highlight');
    } else {
      label.removeClass('highlight');
    }
  } else if (e.type === 'focus') {

    if ($this.val() === '') {
      label.removeClass('highlight');
    } else if ($this.val() !== '') {
      label.addClass('highlight');
    }
  }

});

$('.tab a').on('click', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');

  target = $(this).attr('href');

  $('.tab-content > div').not(target).hide();

  $(target).fadeIn(600);

});
```

EDIT: As requested, the HTML is as follows:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Control Panel</title>
    <link href="/elitlcsys/styles/cp.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/elitlcsys/js/cp.js" rel="alternate" type="text/javascript" />
    </head>

   <body>
  <div class="form">
  <ul class="tab-group">
    <li class="tab"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li class="tab active"><a href="#login">Log In</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#forgetpass">Forgot Password</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="signup">   
      <h1>Sign Up for Free</h1>

      <form action="/" method="post">

      <div class="top-row">
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>
            First Name<span class="req">*</span>
          </label>
          <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" />
        </div>

        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>
            Last Name<span class="req">*</span>
          </label>
          <input type="text"required autocomplete="off"/>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="email"required autocomplete="off"/>
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Set A Password<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="button button-block"/>Get  Started</button>

      </form>

      </div>

    <div id="login">   
      <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>

      <form action="/" method="post">

        <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="email"required autocomplete="off"/>
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Password<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
      </div>

      <p class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>

      <button class="button button-block"/>Log In</button>

      </form>

    </div>

   <div id="forgetpass">   
      <h1>Want your password back?</h1>

     <form action="/" method="post">

        <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="email"required autocomplete="off"/>
      </div>

      <p class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>

      <button class="button button-block"/>Send Password</button>

      </form>

    </div>

  </div><!-- tab-content -->

  </div> <!-- /form -->
   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: can you show what you've written for your HTML?

Comment: Just posted, thank you for trying to answer my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put style="display:none" inline on the divs you don't want to show on page load.